# How to get children from looping `groups'?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

In my `svg` element, there is no.of groups. particulary i am selection some of group by basis of it `class`. works.

After i pick the `group` i am looping using `each` iterater. in the loop how can i find the child element with some of class name.  I tried but not working, any one correct my pelase?

My try:

```
var fadeHandler = function () {
    //group class
    d3.selectAll('.subAppGroupDetail').each(function () {
        var arc = d3.select(this)
                  .select(d3.select('.subAppGroupDetail'))   
                  //.subAppGroupDetail path name
                  .style('opacity', 1); //changing opacity
    })
}

fadeHandler(); // calling function
```

Comment: Could you post an example of your svg structure?

Comment: It is very long function.  i have a multiple groups, in the group i would like to select the child underneath and applying some opacity. since i need to increase the opacity of multiple child i require this.

Comment: @mef, for trial purpose i made this: http://jsfiddle.net/cz2wzkyn/ can you try here?

Answer (score 0):

To select the children elements, you can just chain two `.selectAll` this way:

```
d3.selectAll('.parentClass').selectAll('.childClass')
```

You don't need to use `.each`.

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/cz2wzkyn/1/

P.S.: in the example of code  you posted in the question you are using the same name for parent and child class, you may want to check whether this is correct.

Comment: I need to select each of them seperately using `each` to add different timing of animations. (i will add the different delay times) - can you update you solution

Comment: You can use`.delay(function(d) {...}` for this purpose. cf. [API reference](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#delay). (still no need of `.each`)

Comment: can you give me the solution for this: i have 6 group. each contains 1 path and 1 group. i want to apply first group and first path opacity as `1` and the sibling `group` need to have the same once the path opacity done. after i need to proceed with next group.. like so? how to handle this

Comment: In case of `each` iterator, I can get each `group` seperately, from the group i can select the `path` for animation, once that done, i will select `group` (sibling of path) and put for animation.

Comment: You can also do this without `each`. Store your child selection in a variable, then access the path and group independently.